# read unique char: 'あ' from json file in java

Tags: java, json, ascii

I am reading a JSON file in Java using this code:

```java
String data = Files.readFile(jsonFile)
    .trim()
    .replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "")
    .replaceAll("[\\p{Cntrl}&&[^\r\n\t]]", "")
    .replaceAll("\\p{C}", "");
```

In my JSON file, there is a unique char: 'あ' (12354) that is interpreted to: "" (nothing) when reading the file.

How can I make this char show up in my variable "data"?

---

Due to answers I've got, I understand that the data is cleaned from high ASCII characters by adding `replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "")`. But what can I do if I want all high ASCII characters to be cleaned except this one 'あ'?

Comment: You are removing it with `.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "")`. The method `Files.readFile(jsonFile)` will produce a String with a Character U+3042 (12354) in it. You then strip out all Characters not in the range U+0000 to U+007F (0 to 127) with the first `replaceAll` call.

Comment: As David Conneely commented, you're searching and replacing all non-ASCII letters by using `replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "")`.

Comment: @OrlyOrly If I may ask, *why* are you removing non-ASCII characters?

Comment: @MC Emperor At the end of every line in my JSON file, i got one of those [ ^\\x00-\\x7F ] characters. although I can't see them when I open the JSON file manually, the readFile function gets them.

Comment: I think I have to read the file by another encoding, but what encode?

Comment: You should *always* use UTF-8 to read JSON files. What class is `Files.readFile`? Can we see its source code? (I ask this because I got the feeling that replacing text within this JSON *may* be the solution to the wrong problem, i.e. this may be an *[XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)*.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character you want is the unicode character HIRAGANA LETTER A and has code U+3042.

You can simply add it to the list of valid characters:

```
...
.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F\\u3042]", "")
...
```